# Under what circumstances will virtual threads expand the number of underlying carrier threads?

Tags: java, java-21, virtual-threads

In the jep444, I see "The implementations of these blocking operations compensate for the capture of the OS thread by temporarily expanding the parallelism of the scheduler".
Under what circumstances will virtual threads expand the number of underlying carrier threads?

Can you give me some code to reach this?

Comment: Maybe when you’re using `synchronized` a lot.

Comment: @Holger `synchronized` alone isn't that much of a problem - but _blocking operations inside `synchronized`_ would cause pinning - However, I don't think the OP is asking about pinning but things like file I/O that temporarily increases the number of platform threads in the pool.

Comment: @dan1st the thread is pinned the entire time it owns the object’s monitor (the entire `synchronized` block when not using `wait`) though you’re right that this is not a problem when the thread does not use blocking operations. But keep in mind that trying to enter a `synchronized` block also is a blocking operation when another thread own the object’s monitor. So nested `synchronized` blocks (on different objects) alone are sufficient to create an actual problem.

Comment: Pinning from `synchronized` blocks doesn't temporarily increase the number of carrier threads IIRC. As I said, I think the OP is asking about things like `FileInputStream` which is not yet implemented asynchronously. Also, if you have high-contention nested `synchronized` blocks (i.e. the inner one is contended) or `synchronized` blocks that take a long time without blocking, you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @dan1st 丹1st You'are right that I'm not asking about pinning. Pinning will not cause carrier threads expansion.
I want to know what operation will cause carrier threads expansion. Could you give me some  code to reach this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Any code blocking on `FileInputStream#read`/`FileOutputStream#write` (you might need `FileOutputStream#flush` after writing) in virtual threads should work - but I don't know about other ways/I don't have a full list.

Comment: @dan1st Sorry, how can I print the number of  carrier threads?

Comment: @dan1st You're right. I have sawn the carrier threads expansion in `FileInputStream#read`  by `jstack pid`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CarrierThreadExpandTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
        File file = new File("/Users/info.log");
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                        int content;
                        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                            System.out.print((char) content);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
    }
}
```

```
$ jps
$ jstack pid
```

look at the "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-xx" thread.